# how to retrieve the data from cloud Firestore in flutter?

Tags: flutter

We are trying to fetch the data from cloud Firestore but we unable to find that how  admin fetch all the information about user like their appointment

[image]

[image]

Comment: please specify your issue description.

Comment: Have you tried with where ? yourCollection
          .where('username', isEqualTo: 'neha')

Comment: yes, but we are feteching the user data but in admin dashboard we are retrieve only user login details not appointment details of users

Comment: thanks for giving the code but this code is already done for fetching the user data

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are using the plugin [cloud_firestore](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore) to fetch the data from the firestore

initialize the firestore with your credentials which can be copied from your google_services.json file

```
final FirebaseApp app = await FirebaseApp.configure(
    name: 'test',
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
      googleAppID: '1:79601577497:ios:5f2bcc6ba8cecddd',
      gcmSenderID: '79601577497',
      apiKey: 'AIzaSyArgmRGfB5kiQT6CunAOmKRVKEsxKmy6YI-G72PVU',
      projectID: 'flutter-firestore',
    ),
  );
  final Firestore firestore = Firestore(app: app);
```

to fetch your documents

```
  CollectionReference get users=> firestore.collection('users');
  await users.where('name', isEqualTo: 'neha').getDocuments();
```

or

```
Firestore.instance.collection('users').where('name', isEqualTo: 'neha')
    .snapshots.listen(
          (data) => print('grower ${data.documents[0]['name']}')
    );
```